# Is it possible to make the destination server of a proxy to send response to the the original requester? (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, redirect, proxy, server

I want my clients to request `server 2` to send them some data. But I want their request to go through `server 1` and to add some confidential data to these request. After adding these confidential data to the request I will redirect it to the `server 2`. But I don't want `server 2` to send its response to `server 1`. Indeed, I want `server 2` to send the data directly to the original requester without passing the response data through `server 1`. This is because the response data is huge and it would slow down the `server 1`. I don't have any access to change any code in `server 2` and it's indeed Amazon S3 server.

My question is that is it possible to do that, especially in Node.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, server 1 will have to receive the response from server 2 and then send that data back to the client. You can minimize the memory usage on server 1 by streaming the data to/from server 2 back to the client though. Using the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) npm package you can do this fairly easily:

```
// server 1
var request = require('request')
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  req
    .pipe(request('http://server2.com' + req.path, {
      headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + mySpecialToken }
    }))
    .pipe(res)
})
```